# Using AttachTo in Entity Framwork Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a generic CRUD repository that attaches an updated object to the ObjectContext using `AttachTo` as below:

**N.B. the property `entitySetName` supplies the name of the table the object is being attached to**

```
    public virtual void Save(TModel t)
    {
            TModel unboxed = (TModel)t;
            db.AttachTo(entitySetName, unboxed);
            db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

No errors show up, just doesnt save the data. Can anyone see why?

Comment: is it actually attaching to anything? Is this a new record or updating an existing? Wrap in a try catch to see if you are getting an exception

Comment: Unfortunately no exception is thrown. It is an UPDATED OBJECT that does exist in the database already. When I break the code on the AttachTo statement I can see that the entitysetname being returned is correct and valid.

Comment: Is the code working for other scenarios.  AttachTo takes an EntitySetName and an Object that shoudl be an Entity in the COntext.  The Unbox puzzles me. Why is that necessary . AttachTo expects an Object.  Have you decompiled AttachTo to see what it does?

Comment: @soadyp: I havent got this code to work anywhere else, no. The unboxing was a requirement from the Linq2SQL CRUD repository that this was derived from - im not sure that it is necessary with Entity Framework. I havent decompiled AttachTo, I was hoping the solution to this would be simple enough not to have to :)

Answer (score 2):

`AttachTo` adds an entity to the context in state `Unchanged`. When you call `SaveChanges` immediately after that nothing gets updated because - from EF perspective - the entity is "unchanged".

You need to set the state to `Modified` to tell EF that properties have changed and should be written to the database:

```
public virtual void Save(TModel t)
{
        TModel unboxed = (TModel)t;
        db.AttachTo(entitySetName, unboxed);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(unboxed, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I will test this now. Matter of interest, my version of Entity Framework required `db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(unboxed).SetModified();` on line 5

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to modify by a single column. You can try the `.Attach`.

```
    public virtual void Save(TModel t)
    {
        db.SystemUserLogs.Attach(t);
        //db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified; //<--- For whole fields modifier

        db.Entry(t).Property(x => x.entitySetName).IsModified = true; //<--- For one field modifier
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: He is using `ObjectContext`, not `DbContext`. `entitySetName` is ... well ... the entity set name (just a string), not a property of any entity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attachto(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Slauma, maybe .. i am wrong because i did not tried the `ObjectContext` but what is the `.Attach` of `ObjectContext`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx

Comment: That is an overload you can use when the entities are derived from `EntityObject` (not POCOs). My point was more the `Entry...Property...` stuff which does not work with `ObjectContext` (there is something similar: `ObjectStateEntry.SetModifiedProperty`) and that `entitySetName` is not a property.